# Facebook Profile images not loading on FireTV Firefox browser?

Tags: firefox, facebook-graph-api, amazon-fire-tv

I'm building a webapp that I want to use on a FireTV browser (Firefox) and when I do so, my Facebook images are appearing as broken links.

The images appear normally on all other devices/browsers I've tested (multiple on OSX, Android)

Initially I thought the the firetv browser wasn't liking hot-linked images for some reason as I'm loading them via the graph API, however I'm able to get images hotlinked from other sites to show up just fine on the fireTV as well.... It seems to be something specific about the facebook URLs it doesn't like? Does anyone have any ideas, or know of any tools to help debug it better?

This is what the img elements look like that I'm rendering, for example:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/112816289586034/picture?type=large" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Graph API returns a profile photo URL with a 302 redirect, which apparently is not Amazon FireTV friendly.

The solution was to include redirect=false as a url parameter on the API request, which causes FB to return a JSON object including regular image url that loads as expected.